# Use option[value=""] in jQuery selector with tag select in object

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I'm looking for a way to target option value with a select from a variable.

I target my select like this:

```
var elem_reference = $(this).find('tr').closest('.reference');
```

Now I want to do something like this:

```
$(elem_reference+'option[value="'+id_article+'"]').attr('selected','selected');
```

I know this way doesn't work. I can't combine a object with string selector but I don't see how to proceed. I already try something like this:

```
$(elem_reference).filter('option[value="'+id_article+'"]').attr('selected','selected');
```

and many other ways but that doesn't work.

Comment: You are looking for the `find` method. Also jQuery website **is** your friend!

Comment: You say i can do that :
`$(elem_reference).find('option[value="'+id_article+'"]').attr('selected','selected');`

Because this is not work...

I want to do :
`$('target_select option[value="'+id_article+'"]').attr('selected','selected');`

But with the select in a var, have you an example with find ?

PS: the doc of find i already know... https://api.jquery.com/find/ if you resolve that with find i owe you a beer ;-)

Comment: Just use `elem_reference.val(id_article)`. Setting the value of a `<select>` is the same as setting the `selected` attribute of the corresponding option.

Comment: Note: you should be using [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `attr` when setting Boolean attributes like `selected`, `checked`, etc.. But @Barmar has it right; just call [`val(value)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: It's complicated because my select was transform to combobox on the fly by a template, i use 3 lines : 

`$('.reference').val(id_article);
$('.reference  ption[value="'+id_article+'"]').attr('selected','selected');
$('.reference').prev().find('span').text(liste_article[id_article]['reference']);`

I need all the 3 line to all work synchronisation between combobox and input in same line. (I d'ont know why when i just use val,  no selected writted in source and the text is not replace by the new one)

That why my question is about combine jquery objet + string for the selector)

Comment: Selecting an option dynamically doesn't change the HTML, it's a property of the select element.

Comment: When i look in dev console i can show the dynamic change (also select appear and disappear in option) or we don't speek about the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way,
First my selectors was invert, instead of :

```
var elem_reference = $(this).find('tr').closest('.reference');
```

I had to use :

```
var elem_reference = $(this).closest('tr').find('.reference');
```

And to solve my problem (not very elegant way) I use :

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.reference option[value="'+id_article+'"]').prop('selected', true);
```

I don't really like that but that do the job for now.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you can do it like that:

```
 $($(this).find('tr').closest('.reference')).find('option[value="'+id_article+'"]').attr('selected',true);
```

Comment: I think it's look like what i'm looking for with the selector in a var.
Thanks